# Apply an endomorphism to elements of different types in a pair

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In short, I would like the following to type-check in Haskell:

```hs
both f (x, y) = (f x, f y)

foo :: ([Int], [Char])
foo = ([1], "a")

bar :: ([Int], [Char])
bar = both (concat . replicate 3) foo  -- intended: ([1, 1, 1], "aaa")
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘Int’
  Expected: ([Int], [Int])
    Actual: ([Int], [Char])
• In the second argument of ‘both’, namely ‘foo’
  In the expression: both (concat . replicate 3) foo
  In an equation for ‘bar’: bar = both (concat . replicate 3) foo
```

I got it to compile after I added the following type annotation to `both`:

```hs
both :: (forall x. [x] -> [x]) -> ([a], [b]) -> ([a], [b])
both f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
```

But this solution does not feel completely satisfactory because `both` seems like more generic, so that, for instance `both id (1, "a")` is accepted as well. Can I somehow go further from here?

Comment: What's wrong with `both id (1, "a")`?

Comment: That it doesn't type check when it's annotated with `both :: (forall x. [x] -> [x]) -> ([a], [b]) -> ([a], [b])`, sorry for weird wording

Comment: Haskell's type system (with GHC extensions) is rich, but it isn't rich enough to type `both` in full generality.  The best you'll be able to do is something like @leftroundabout's answer.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about my duplicate closure, since it's asking about the broader question of any polymorphic function, not specifically an endomorphism. But the answers there still look quite helpful.

Comment: One of the sad facts of higher-rank types is that you do not get principal types. That is, there are terms for which no single type generalizes all the other types it can be given. So it may in fact be the case that there *cannot* be a "completely satisfactory" type to give to `both`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider this to be the most sensible version:

```
both :: ∀ t a b . (∀ x . t x -> t x) -> (t a, t b) -> (t a, t b)
both f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
```

Your list example is a special case of this by way of `t ~ []`, but it can also used with other containers and indirectly also with "un-contained" values since you can always use [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) – though that is basically useless since the only function `∀ x . x -> x` is `id`.

Comment: Note that it would be reasonable to further generalize to different input and output functors: `both :: forall s t a b. (forall x. s x -> t x) -> (s a, s b) -> (t a, t b)`.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr yes, that is reasonable. (It only makes a difference when we go beyond endomorphisms, but it's natural to do this.)

Comment: Oh, I think missed the "endomorphism" bit in the question title.

Comment: I asked about endomorphisms, but this example is very helpful in seeing the bigger picture, thank you!